# xslt 2.0 format-number repeating pattern with alternate group-separator

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm trying to understand why `XSLT 2.0` is repeating the following pattern when I attempt to provide an alternate `grouping-separator` to the `format-number` function like so:

```
 <xsl:decimal-format grouping-separator="-" name="hyphenFormatting"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="format-number(642120, '####-##', 'hyphenFormatting')"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Output: `64-21-20` when I expected the output to be: `6421-20`

Is there a way I can bypass this pattern repetition so it evaluates my mask literally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Saxon? With Saxon 9.8 I get the same behaviour as you do.

The specification was rephrased between 2.0 and 3.0. In 2.0 it says:

> In addition, if these integer-part-grouping-positions are at regular
> intervals (that is, if they form a sequence N, 2N, 3N, ... for some
> integer value N, including the case where there is only one number in
> the list), then the sequence contains all integer multiples of N as
> far as necessary to accommodate the largest possible number.

While 3.0 says the following (the third rule is new):

> The grouping is defined to be regular if the following conditions
> apply:
>
> - There is an least one grouping-separator in the integer part of the sub-picture.
> - There is a positive integer G (the grouping size) such that the position of every grouping-separator in the integer part of the
>   sub-picture is a positive integer multiple of G.
> - Every position in the integer part of the sub-picture that is a positive integer multiple of G is occupied by a grouping-separator.
>
> If the grouping is regular, then the integer-part-grouping-positions sequence contains all integer
> multiples of G as far as necessary to accommodate the largest possible
> number.

So your grouping is regular under the 2.0 definition but not under the 3.0 definition. Saxon is apparently implementing the 2.0 definition. I suspect the change was intended as a bug fix, and it appears Saxon has not implemented this change.

As a workaround, you could define the picture as

```
#-###############################################-##
```

with the extra grouping separator placed so far out to the left that you will never have a number this large.

(Raised a Saxon issue here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3669)

Comment: Very good explanation @MichaelKay, I am using `Saxon 9.5`.  Thank you for opening the issue ticket.  I'll keep an eye on it.